# Realm on Swift - Creating Relationship

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-list

I have two classes that form a one to many relationship:

```
class FooA: Object {
    dynamic var someAValue: String

    let fooBList = List<FooB>()
}

class FooB: Object {
    dynamic var someBValue: String
}
```

I add the object into Realm in this fashion:

```
let fooA = FooA()

fooA.someAValue = 'a value'

let fooB = FooB()

fooB.someBValue = 'a value'

fooA.fooBList.append(fooB)

let realm = try! Realm()

try! realm.write {
   realm.add(fooA)
}
```

Everything goes well, the object is inserted into Realm.  However, when I attempt to access the FooB object like this:

```
fooA.fooBList[0]
```

It goes BOOM and the app crashes!  So, obviously, I did not insert the relationship object into Realm correctly and the relationship is corrupted.  What did I miss in the Realm documentation? Must I create the Array first and add it to the parent object in another fashion?

To update on my question, this is the operation that wants to blow up:

```
FooApiClient.getFooAObjects()
        .subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler(qos: .default))
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
        .subscribe { [weak self] in
            switch $0 {
            case .next(let fooAObjects):
                self?.fooAObjects = fooAObjects
            case .completed:

                self?.fooTableView.reloadData()

                loadingView?.hide()

            case .error(let error):
                loadingView?.hide()

                self?.handleError(error)

                self?.showNoFooView()
            }
        }
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

The invocation: self?.fooTableView.reloadData() causes to the table view to attempt to display the foo objects retrieved and where it goes BOOM.

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting?

Comment: It throws an uncaught error that crashes the app, there is no 'error' or error message that is given.

Comment: When do you access `fooA.fooBList[0]`? after saving? You could also download the realm [db browser](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#realm-browser)

Comment: Yes, I retrieve all objects from Realm and iterate across them within the UITableViewDataSource.cellForRowAt ...

Comment: If I open the default.realm database, I can see the relationship and even click on the 'link' to look at the FooB objects.

Comment: If I restart the app, the data (and the relationship data) is able to be retrieved.  This leads me to believe that I am trying to access 'live' data that has not been 'committed'.  When I add data, do I have to 'commit' the transaction?  I did not see that in the documentation.

Comment: Data within the Realm file is internally stored in versions. A write transaction creates a new version that reflects the modifications made in that transaction. A given `Realm` instance exposes the contents of a single version within the Realm file. On threads with runloops, such as the main thread, the version that is exposed automatically updates to the latest version whenever changes are committed to the Realm file. On threads without runloops, `Realm` instances must be manually advanced via `Realm.refresh()` to see the new data. This may explain why you're not seeing data you expect to see

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. It may have some mistakes.

```
class SomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var fooA  : FooA?

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let realm = try! Realm()
        if let aFooA = realm.objects(FooA.self).first{
            fooA = aFooA
            self.reloadTableView()
        }
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let _ = fooA{
        return fooA!.fooBList.count
    }

    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SomeCell", for: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...
    let fooB = fooA!.fooBList[indexPath.row]
    cell.titleLabel.text = fooB.someBValue

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: So, for grins and giggles, I tried to do a print(fooA.someValue) within cellForRowAt and I am getting a: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::IncorrectThreadException: Realm accessed from incorrect thread.

Comment: using my code? I have similar code on one project right now and it works. You should access your realm object on the same thread.

Comment: I retrieve the data from the service using RxSwift, insert it into Realm and give it over to the ViewController for display.  How do I ensure it is the correct thread?

Comment: I don't know how RsSwift actually works, but maybe the response form the server is handled on a background thread? do you create your realm object and push to the new view controller there? Maybe instead of passing the object, pass the PK and fetch the object on that new VC.